# Python "%env" invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the following code to download a dataset that will be used to train a QA model.

```
# set path with magic
%env DATA_DIR=./data/squad 

# download the data
def download_squad(version=1):
    if version == 1:
        !wget -P $DATA_DIR https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/train-v1.1.json
        !wget -P $DATA_DIR https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v1.1.json
    else:
        !wget -P $DATA_DIR https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/train-v2.0.json
        !wget -P $DATA_DIR https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v2.0.json
            
download_squad(version=2)
```

When I run the code, I get the error

```
%env DATA_DIR=./data/squad
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you want to look at the tutorial I'm following, the link is here https://qa.fastforwardlabs.com/pytorch/hugging%20face/wikipedia/bert/transformers/2020/05/19/Getting_Started_with_QA.html

What is going wrong at this step? Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you're running isn't Python.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial they are using google colab notebook.

Shell commands including magic should work there.

[google colab shell commands](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.05-IPython-And-Shell-Commands.ipynb)

Comment: The tutorial gives the choice to work in google colab or on your own machine. I guess I don't have to do this step then because its for the google colab tutorial?

Comment: You can directly copy the wget commands and specialize where to download the files. Run it in the terminal with $DATA_DIR being the directory you wish to download the data to. You have to do this step in order to get the dataset you want to train your model on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Ipython for this command. As shown [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics)

%alias
Defines an alias for a system command.

‘%alias alias_name cmd’ defines ‘alias_name’ as an alias for ‘cmd’

As you can see its just an alias and you can easily work around it if you wish to continue your tutorial on Python